# Normal closure of a nilpotent subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is there a finite non-solvable group $G$ with a nilpotent subgroup  $H$ satisfying its normal closure $H^G=G$? We guess that the answer is negative in the case that $H$ is S-semipermutable.($H$ is S-semipermutable
in $G$ if $H$ permutes with every Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$ for primes $q$ not dividing
$|H|$.)

Comment: Is $H^G$ the normal closure of $H$ in $G$, as the title suggests ?

Comment: @CaptainLama Yes.

Comment: Have you some ideas that you've tried to apply to solve this?

Comment: @hardmath In the case that the set of prime divisors of |G| and |H| are equal, We know that if the answer is positive then the set of prime divisors of |H| has at least 3 members.

Comment: I suggest adding a paragraph about that to your Question.  Comments are less visible to your Readers than the Question itself, so (for example) I edited to add your earlier clarification about the normal closure.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is finite, then $G$ must always have a *nilpotent* subgroup $H$ with $H^G=G$. This can be seen by induction on $|G|$. If $G$ has a maximal subgroup $H$ that is not normal in $G$, then the result follows by induction applied to $H$. Otherwise all maximal subgroups are normal, which implies that $G$ itself is nilpotent.